# Is this proof correct: $\liminf {\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi n}{8})n^n}{n!}} = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Evaluate a limit of a sequence: $\liminf {\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi n}{8})n^n}{n!}}$.

Proof: $\liminf {\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi n}{8})n^n}{n!}} = 0$.
Since a product of convergent sequence and a bounded sequence is convergent, $\liminf {\frac{sin(\frac{\pi n}{8})n^n}{n!}} = \lim{\frac{n^n}{n!} \cdot \liminf{sin(\frac{\pi n}{8})}}$.

So $\liminf {\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi n}{8})n^n}{n!}} = 0 \cdot (-1) = 0$.

Is this proof correct with all steps properly justified?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n}{n!}=\infty$...

Comment: I see. I just thought that factorial grows faster then everything. So does this sequence diverge and $\liminf = \infty$? Can I rigorously prove it?

Comment: @user0347284: While what carmichael wrote is true, it is irrelevant because you have $\liminf$ as opposed to $\lim$. In your case, $\sin(\pi n/8)=-1$ for $n=12k$, so it actually goes to $-\infty$

Comment: It turns out that $n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n$; this is called Stirling's formula. I believe the liminf of your sequence should be $-\infty$, since $\sin(\frac{\pi n}{8})=-1$ when $n=12,28,44,\dots$

Comment: The value of  $\lim  \inf \sin (\pi n/8)$ is irrelevant. What you want is that the sequence $(\sin (\pi n/8)_n$ is bounded. Which is obvious, as every term in that sequence belongs to $[-1,1].$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your proof is not correct.

Consider the subsequence $n_k:=12+16k$ for $k\geq 0$, then
$$\sin(\pi n_k/8)=\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+2k\pi\right)=-1.$$
Moreover for $n\geq 2$
$$\frac{n^n}{n!}=n\cdot\prod_{j=2}^n\frac{n}{j}\geq n.$$
(which means that the sequence $\frac{n^n}{n!}$ is unbounded!).
Hence
$$\liminf_{n\to+\infty} {\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi n}{8})n^n}{n!}}
\leq -\lim_{k\to+\infty} \frac{{n_k}^{n_k}}{n_k!}\leq -\lim_{k\to+\infty} n_k=-\infty.$$